# Datatables don't load content of database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, datatables

I'm trying to load users from a table in my database using datatables(https://datatables.net/) but the page is not loading anything at all. I'm getting these errors when I open the console
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykNTL.png

I loaded the js and css here in this order:

[uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at dataTables.bootstrap.min.js:5 at dataTables.bootstrap.min.js:5][1]

> ```
>     <script src="~/lib/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="~/lib/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
>     <scripts src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></scripts>
>     <scripts src="~/plugins-site/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></scripts>
>     <link href="~/lib/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>     <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
> ```
>
> />

Comment: I don't see the core jQuery library listed in your question. That needs to be added as the first item in your list (for example, from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js).

Comment: thanks I added it to the top and the jquery error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the page is not loading anything at all  after add Query library i reccommend   add before link of script `defer` after that the table load every script
make links like this

```
<script defer  src="~/lib/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
```

read this [script-async-defer](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer)